# How to create a reusable CustomTextField?

Tags: swiftui

We can create reusable views like CardView confirming to View protocol.
Like that how can we create custom reusable text fields?

As we use a `TextField` provided in SwiftUI like

`TextField("Enter your name", text: $name)`

Similarly how to create your own reusable `TextField` with a specific style (cornerRadius, borders)

Example: `CustomTextField("Enter your name", text: $name)`

Comment: please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and cosider it. please show us what you tried so far so we can help you, but this is not a "we write code for you for free"-platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't subclass in SwiftUI.  You *can* create a reusable component based around a `TextField` or create a modifier in order to style the `TextField`s throughout your app.

I would recommend the modifier approach:

```swift
struct MyTextFieldModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding(8.0)
            .background(Color.white.cornerRadius(8.0))
            .shadow(radius: 24.0)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

And then to use it:

```
TextField("Title", text: self.$text)
  .modifier(MyTextFieldModifier()) // Your TextField will now have a shadow and a background.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can create an custom TextFiled by creating a subclass of UITextFiled
and write the UI inside that here is an example

```
class UnderLineTextField: UITextField {
          override func layoutSubviews() {
                super.layoutSubviews()
                borderView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height , width: self.frame.size.width, height: 1.0)
                self.addSubview(borderView)
            }
        }
```

And you can subclass these UnderLineTextField for the textfield you need

Answer (score 0):

Reusable custom TextField can be created by many ways, one of the way is using custom TextFieldStyle

```
struct CustomTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>)-> some View {
        configuration
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            .frame(height: 42)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(Color.gray))
            .accentColor(Color.black)
    }
}
```

And can be used like

```
TextField("First text field", text: $text1)
    .textFieldStyle(CustomTextFieldStyle())
TextField("Second text field", text: $text2)
    .textFieldStyle(CustomTextFieldStyle())
```

You can refer [this article](https://thehappyprogrammer.com/custom-textfield-in-swiftui/) for some other ways to create reusable custom TextField

Comment: Using private/unpublished methods is always discouraged.